# Can one obtain variable batch sizes for LSTM's in TensorFlow without using Placeholders?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

In my implementation of an LSTM RNN, I used the following line of code:

```
self.batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
```

Where x was a tensor obtained from the dataset api.  Printing x gave the following output:

```
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(?, 2, 1024), dtype=float32)
```

The rest of my code is given by

```
    targets = tf.one_hot(y,num_classes)

    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell
    cells = [cell(num_units=n) for n in num_units]
    stacked_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells, state_is_tuple=True)
    initial_state = stacked_rnn_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)


...

    output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        stacked_rnn_cell, prev_output, initial_state = initial_state, dtype = tf.float32, 
        sequence_length = [1024]*self.batch_size)

    logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(output[-1],24)

    xent = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels = targets, logits = logits)

    self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(xent)
    self.opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).\
        minimize(self.loss,global_step=global_step)
    self.metric_loss,self.update_loss = tf.metrics.mean(self.loss)
    self.summary = tf.summary.scalar('Loss',self.update_loss)
```

I'm met with the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1024,2] vs. shape[1] = [1,128]
```

1024 is the batch size, 2 is the input size, 128 is the state size.

If I change the first line to

```
self.batch_size = 1024
```

or any other constant number, it trains.  I'd rather not handle this with placeholders and just infer the value from the data sample so I can keep it general.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!  The problem line is

```
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    stacked_rnn_cell, prev_output, initial_state = initial_state, dtype = tf.float32, 
    sequence_length = [1024]*self.batch_size)
```

If we change it to:

```
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    stacked_rnn_cell, polar, initial_state = initial_state, dtype = tf.float32, 
    sequence_length = tf.tile([1024],[self.batch_size]))
```

It seems to work as expected.